# How to Iterate and calculate for every tenth index values

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to calculate for elements from index 0-10, 11-21 etc. Then i want to take the average value of every tenth index value, for then to find the maximum of the averages. My problem i think, lays in iteration and calculating for every 10th element in the list.

```
dataGrowth =[2,3,4,5,1,34,4,2,5,6,7,6,4,545,3,434,2,1,2,4,6,723,1,3,547,47,4,23,3]
ddSMA = 10
for i in range(len(dataGrowth)):
  if i >= 10:
    currentVal = dataGrowth[i]
    print(firstTenVals)
    firstTenVals = dataGrowth[i-ddSMA : i]
    maxVal = max(lastTenVals)        
    averageDrawDown = (currentVal - maxVal)/maxVal
```

My output of the list only remove the first value after iterating,

> ```
> > [2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 34, 4, 2, 5, 6] [3, 4, 5, 1, 34, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7] [4, 5,
> > 1, 34, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 6] [5, 1, 34, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 6, 4] [1, 34, 4, 2,
> > 5, 6, 7, 6, 4, 545] [34, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 6, 4, 545, 3] [4, 2, 5, 6, 7,
> > 6, 4, 545, 3, 434] [2, 5, 6, 7, 6, 4, 545, 3, 434, 2] [5, 6, 7, 6, 4,
> > 545, 3, 434, 2, 1] [6, 7, 6, 4, 545, 3, 434, 2, 1, 2] [7, 6, 4, 545,
> > 3, 434, 2, 1, 2, 4] [6, 4, 545, 3, 434, 2, 1, 2, 4, 6] [4, 545, 3,
> > 434, 2, 1, 2, 4, 6, 723] [545, 3, 434, 2, 1, 2, 4, 6, 723, 1] [3, 434,
> > 2, 1, 2, 4, 6, 723, 1, 3] [434, 2, 1, 2, 4, 6, 723, 1, 3, 547] [2, 1,
> > 2, 4, 6, 723, 1, 3, 547, 47] [1, 2, 4, 6, 723, 1, 3, 547, 47, 4] [2,
> > 4, 6, 723, 1, 3, 547, 47, 4, 23]
> ```

Comment: Your english is not very clear and neither is your goal. You should edit this question and be more clear and specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that, maybe:

```
d = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

n = 5

print ([ sum(d[i*n:(i+1)*n])/n for i in range(len(d)//n) ])
```

Output:

```
[3.0, 8.0, 13.0, 18.0]
```

It takes the list `d`, slices this list every `n` elements and compute the mean for each slice.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided shouldn't even work because the variables are being called without being assigned.

So your if statement is incorrect. Basically what you are doing is calculating the average every time i is bigger than 10 and not for every 10 values. Here is how you do for every ten values:

```
dataGrowth =[2,3,4,5,1,34,4,2,5,6,7,6,4,545,3,434,2,1,2,4,6,723,1,3,547,47,4,23,3]
ddSMA = 10

for i in range(len(dataGrowth)):
    if i % 10==0 and i!=0:

        currentVal = dataGrowth[i]

        ten_values = dataGrowth[i-10:i]
 
        maxVal = max(ten_values)
        averageDrawDown = (currentVal - maxVal)/maxVal
        print(averageDrawDown)
```

If you wish to determine the max average then save the averages in a list and get its max value.

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear to me what you're trying to do, but here's some code that might be helpful.

```
dataGrowth = [   2,   3,   4,   5,   1,  34,   4,   2,   5,   6, 
                 7,   6,   4, 545,   3, 434,   2,   1,   2,   4, 
                 6, 723,   1,   3, 547,  47,   4,  23,   3 ]
```

First ten values:

```
first_ten_values = dataGrowth[:10]
print(first_ten_values)
```

Result:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 4, 2, 5, 6]
```

Every tenth value:

```
every_tenth_value = [dataGrowth[i] for i in range(9, len(dataGrowth), 10)]
print(every_tenth_value)
```

Result:

```
[6, 4]
```

Average of every tenth value:

```
average_of_every_tenth_value = sum(every_tenth_value) / len(every_tenth_value)
print(average_of_every_tenth_value)
```

Result:

```
5.0
```